# Django - load statics

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to load static file into my html files. index.html extends base.html. However, files are not read(at least not shown on the screen, however, the terminal doesn't say Not Found)

In the head of index.html and base.html, I have a tag

```
{% load static %}
```

I read .css file by using tag in index.html:

```
{% static 'base/css/style.css' %}
```

In setting.py, I have:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['Grace/templates/',
             'HomePage/templates/',
             'Forum/templates/',
             'CustomUser/templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

my project structure is like this:

```
|Grace
|--static
|----base
|------css
|--------boostrap.min.css
|--------style.css
|------templates
|--------base.html

|Homepage
|--templates
|----index
|------index.html
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inspect your code using F12 and see if you link is their???

Comment: @mohammedqudah it is shown like <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/base/css/style.css"> after inspect. Yeah...it is not linking to the right path. It should be "base/static/css/style.css", am I right? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: your static folder called base??

Comment: @mohammedqudah there is a folder called "static" and under it, there is a folder called "base" which contains css folder

Comment: you said it should be `base/static....` you mean `static/base`

Comment: @mohammedqudah not 100% sure about that. But the web should find the static files from base (there are also other static files for forum, user)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: @Tushortz it is load static in django 1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow this steps:

Let's say that this is your directory:

```
project_folder
├── app_1
├── app_2
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │     ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── fonts
│   └── js
├── templates
```

In your `settings.py` file you have to specify the path to the folder with static files named `static` in my example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

Than in any of your `html` file you can load `boostrap.css` file like that:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
```

Comment: is "BASE_DIR" presenting my directory name or I just need write it in setting?

Comment: and only one static directory is needed for one project, not one for each app, right?

Comment: Variable `BASE_DIR` should be already in your `settings.py`  file. Yes you are right, only one static directory is needed for one project. Please vote up and accept my answer if I helped you.

Comment: actually, still not loaded....I have base, forum, index, user as sub-folder in static, and each sub-folder has its own css, img, js folder. Does it matter?

Comment: sorry, my bad, placed static folder in a wrong place. Your suggestion works good！

Comment: I am happy that's I could helped you.